# How do I fix Invalid Form Type In embed.fields.1.value: This field is required

Tags: discord.py

My friend is trying to setup a number lookup bot on discord, and is having trouble with the embed part. The error is:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body In embed.fields.1.value: This field is required`

and I don't know what is causing this.

This is the code:

```
@client.command()
async def look(ctx, number):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    i = requests.get(f"https://api.telnyx.com/anonymous/v2/number_lookup/{number}")
    response = i.json()
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Mello Carrier Lookup", color=0xFF0000)
    embed.add_field(name="Phone Number", value=f"{str(response['data']['phone_number'])}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Carrier", value=f"{str(response['data']['carrier']['name'])}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Country Code", value=f"{str(response['data']['country_code'])}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="state", value="coming soon", inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is saying that the 2nd (index rules) field of your embed has a blank `value` arg. Discord's embed rules state that all embed fields must have content in them and cannot be blank.

So in your instance its the:

```py
    embed.add_field(name="Carrier", value=f"{str(response['data']['carrier']['name'])}", inline=False)
```

line. Seems like ['name'] is returning a blank str

Comment: I figured out why it wasnt working. The bot didnt have its own role for some odd reason. Thanks though